Matlab standalon application with loaded .net framework
I'm building my Matlab code as a standalone application (exe) using the following command
mcc -v -N -p -m runMyCode.m

I use Matlab 2022b which supports .net 5+.
When I run runMyCode.exe then I log the output of dotnetenv. I states that .NET Framework 4.0.30319.42000 is loaded. The problem is that for some reason .NET is "loaded" at the entry point so if I add dotnetenv("core"), it produces an error:
.NET is loaded. To change the environment, restart MATLAB then call dotnetenv. If I run the exe again, .NET Framework is still loaded.
What I noticed is that if I open Matlab, run dotnetenv("core") and then run mcc then .NET Core is loaded within the exe.
Is there a way to tell mcc what .NET version to be used for building the exe or at least build it in a way that .NET is not loaded?

It does not answer the original question but compiling and running the exe with Matlab 2023a, .NET is not loaded by default so it is possbile to change to .NET core.
